# RoR self-referential search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query in my model defined as

```
def self.seeParent(query)
    where("id LIKE ?", "#{query}")
end
```

What i'm wanting is the rows with id's matching the parent field of the ID supplied by the user. Obviously, all I'm getting now is the row matching the id that was entered. So basically what I want is

```
def self.seeParent(query)
    where("id LIKE ?", "#{query.parent}")
end
```

But I'm unsure of the hash syntax because I am a r00b (ruby noob)
Help?

Comment: You don't need the `#{}`. Just do `where('id like ?', query.parent)`.

Comment: In that case you'll have to provide some information. What is `query`? What does the `parent` method return?

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to this:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

   def see_parent
       SomeModel.find(self.parent_id)
   end

end
```

Comment: I just have one model that will need to do a self join. Attributes are:
ID Guideline Description Investor Program Code Client Parent Guideline Text

So I need the Record(s) with ID matching to the parent field of the record corresponding to the ID entered by the user

Comment: where do you keep your parent_id value? I'm assuming in a column named "parent_id" ?

Comment: yeah it's just called parent

Comment: it's also a standard notation to call you ids, by _id, usually will become a good practice as you move forward, I would suggest renaming your parent column to "parent_id" as a bonus point, since Rails is all about convention. Also, for the method names, use _ when joining two words, that's the standard in Rails too. Good luck!